# Why are these 2 summations not equal to each other?

Tags: taylor-expansion, geometric-series

Why is:$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(x-1)^n}{n}\right) \neq 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^{n}(x-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)$$

This question arose when I tried to get the series representation for ln(x) [centered @ x=1] using geometric series method. I couldn't get it to match. I originally thought maybe it had something to do with the fact that I had: 
$$\frac{1}{1-(1-x)} = \int\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left({(1-x)^n}\right)dx  $$Vs:

$$\frac{1}{1-(-(x-1)} = \int\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left({(-1)^{n}(x-1)^n}\right)dx  $$
But both of the above 2 are the same correct? So I just can't wrap my brain around why the very 1st two summations aren't the same. Don't Geometric series require the index to start at n=0? 
$$$$I feel like there's some basic math principle I have forgotten.. Thanks for the help!

Comment: They are the same; why do you think they aren't?

Comment: If I put them in my calculator with an index up to 4 or evaluate them at some x value I get 2 different answers

Comment: If you truncate the sums in different ways, then you'll get different results. That is, if you stop at $n=4$ in both sums, then you're summing different things (the first one has four terms, the second has five). The infinite sums are equal.

Comment: Well, one going to $4$ would be the other going to $3$.

Comment: omg... **Face-Palm**

Comment: Yup that's what I was missing lol, I knew it was going to be something super silly.. Thank you!!

Comment: So if I want to represent the center @ x = 1 I can do either fraction right (2nd part)? Neither one is wrong?

Comment: @intwarrior they are all the same, indeed $\sum_{k=a}^b g(k)=\sum_{k=a+c}^{b+c}g(k-c)$ because you are just renaming the index notation but what is summed is the same

Comment: Ok cool, I suppose it is nicer to do the little extra work in the beginning and have it is at (x-1) because it's a little more intuitive after the integration. You'd have clear alternating signs vs, well you have negative x's but then you're multiplying by a negative, but then depending on your "n" your negative x's are positive x's and... Neater and quicker in the beginning is not always best haha.

Comment: Also the calculator is so nice to do some crazy factoring for me so it's not obvious it is just 1 extra term lol.